# Tasks.await error: "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that DataReadResponse conforms to DataReadResult"

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

Following [the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient) I’m trying to get Google Fit Data using HistoryClient. DataReadResult should be able to grab a result from the response using Tasks.await(response) but Android Studio is telling me

> Required type: DataReadResult Provided: DataReadResponse no
> instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that DataReadResponse
> conforms to DataReadResult

and the Build fails with

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable TResult has incompatible bounds
                DataReadResult readDataResult = Tasks.await(response);
                                                           
    equality constraints: com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResponse
    upper bounds: com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResult,java.lang.Object
```

Here is my code:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();

            Task<DataReadResponse> response = Fitness.getHistoryClient(activity, googleSignInAccount)
                    .readData(readRequest);
            try {
                DataReadResult readDataResult = Tasks.await(response);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // ...
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ...
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // Task timed out before it could complete.
                // ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, instead of (inside your try block):

```
DataReadResult readDataResult = Tasks.await(response);
```

it should be:

```
DataReadResult readDataResult = response.await();
```